# MonthName() function is not working in windows 8

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, vbscript

Before that i using window 7, I did the use the function MonthName()

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_monthname.asp

my code when using windows 7:

> response.write MonthName(12,True)

result:

> Dec

After upgrading to windows 8, I use back the same function but got different output which the it did not convert the integer 12 to the abbreviated month name but display the integer with a question mark at the back.

my code when using windows 8:

> response.write MonthName(12,True)

result:

> 12?

even if i tried by showing the non-abbreviate month name it shows 3 question mark:

> response.write MonthName(12,True)

output:

> ???

can anybody help??

Comment: Check your regional settings. What is the actual content in the HTML where the 3 question marks appear?